# Issue in storing data into database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created register form using php and jquery. I need to store input details to sql database.

I created config.php and included in index.php and submit.php file.

But still didn't store in database, may i know what is my mistake in config.php code, can anyone please help me?

This is my config.php:

```
    <?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "crop";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    ?>
```

and this is code_exec.php:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include('config.php');
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
    $month=$_POST['month'];
    $day=$_POST['day'];
    $year=$_POST['year'];

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass,`sex_select`, month,day,year)  
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass','$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Read about SQL injections, do not use `mysql_` extension, switch to `mysqli_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As per [**your originally posted question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26228698/1) which has been edited:

Firstly, you are using a hyphen for your `sex-select` column.

MySQL is thinking you want to do a math equation which translates to:

sex (minus) select.

Wrap it in backticks and missing the column for `photo`

```
(fname, lname, email, pass, phone, photo, `sex-select`, month,day,year)
                                   ^^^^^^ missing column
```

having used `mysql_error()` with `mysql_query()` would have signaled the error.

Also `$sex-select` that needs to be `$sex_select` do not use hyphens for variables also.

So change all of those instances to `$sex_select` in your VALUES also.

```
('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass', '$phone', '$photo', '$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')
```

I noticed both your DB and table are named `crop`.

```
$mysql_database = "crop";
```

and

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop...
```

One of those may be incorrect. Make sure that the DB name is what it should be, along with the table. That just doesn't look right to me, but I could be wrong. Only you know what they are called.

Plus `mysql_close($con);` this should be `mysql_close($bd);`
since you're using `$bd = mysql_connect`

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which would have signaled that error also, which is something you are not doing, is checking for errors. This is important during development.

---

**EDIT:** for DB connection error checking:

Instead of:

```
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "crop";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
```

Use the following to catch any errors, should there be any. Using `die("Could not connect database")` is not good enough.

If `crop` is not the database, MySQL will tell you.

```
<?php
$bd = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$bd) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('crop', $bd);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Same for your query:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass, phone, photo, `sex-select`, month,day,year)  
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass', '$phone', '$photo', '$sex-select', '$month','$day','$year')");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Plus, as per your HTML form:

```
<select name="sex-select" id="sex-select">
```

should be

```
<select name="sex_select" id="sex-select">
```

Comment: @Fred-ii-: i removed phone and photo

Comment: @user4112064 Is your column called `sex_select` or `sex-select` in your db table? Also, you need to show us your HTML form. Is there not any errors/warnings coming back as `Undefined index....`? You may need to show use DB schema after this if it does not work. I'm at my end and am sure I have covered everything. It's up to you now to check column types, lengths etc. if both are off, it will fail silently.

Comment: @user4112064 both your database and table are called `crop`? you sure about that? and using at the bottom of my answer `$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass, phone, photo, `sex_select`, month,day,year)  
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass', '$phone', '$photo', '$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}` that will show you the errors.

Comment: please see my code again, index.php and config.php and code_exec.php file

Comment: @user4112064 You have `<select name="sex-select" id="sex-select">` that should be `<select name="sex_select" id="sex-select">`

Comment: ok, but there is no errors to show.. its ok. i will change.

Comment: @user4112064 You also have `<label for="sex-select" name="sex_select">I am:</label>` remove the `name` - `<label for="sex-select">I am:</label>` and these `<?=generate_options(1,12,'callback_month')?>` I don't know what that does.

Comment: yes i removed. @Fred-ii-..

Comment: `<?=generate_options(1,12,'callback_month')?>` the `<?=` that's short tag syntax. If short tags are not set/on, all `<?=` should be changed to `<?php echo` - yet I don't know what the `generate_options()` function does, so that may be JS or datepicker and I won't be able to help you with that. JS is **not** a strong point of mine. Sorry, good luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: now after i entered details, it shows all the fields required. i just confused.

Comment: @user4112064 So, problem solved? Is it working now?

Comment: what problem solved, nothing solved, still didn't store in database.

Comment: You said that 3 times. The problem is elsewhere and I don't know. You will need to figure it out. I've already spent over an hour trying to help you, now you will need to continue. It's most likely in your JS function for the datepicker. Good luck.

Comment: sorry @Fred-ii-: here some net connection problem, so it occurred three times.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: all the codes i posted, please help me to fix this.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, +1 for a great effort. Might be worth knowing the OP has [duplicated their question on a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230114/issue-in-inserting-data-into-mysql-database-using-php). I've VTC.

Comment: @halfer Thanks Halfer. I saw that earlier before going to bed. Spent more than an hour trying to solve it for the OP. Next time something like this happens, OP's going to have to provide DB schema. This is ridiculous. Thanks again Halfer, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

See the query below you will know where you are missing one value for column

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass, phone, missing_Photo_column, `sex-select`, month,day,year)VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass', '$phone', '$photo', 
'$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')");
```

In this query your are missing column for photo.

change this `'$sex-select'` to this `'$sex_select'`

`$sex-select=$_POST['sex-select'];` change this to this `$sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];`

one more think mysql_ function are depricited.

use mysqli_ Function or PDO

For mysqli_ function check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

FOR PDO check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a hyphen in a variable name. Use an underscore instead.

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'
>   http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

You also need to add backticks to your "sex-select" column

```
`sex-select`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use`$sex_select=$_POST['sex-select'];` or use `$sexselect=$_POST['sex-select'];` Because the php Considers `select` tag as mysql select option.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your code_exec.php with the below code -

Note - Please change your input name `sex-select` to `sex_select`. And you are also missing a field name in the query `photo`. please replace with your name which you have created in DB.

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include('config.php');
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $photo=$_POST['photo'];
    $sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
    $month=$_POST['month'];
    $day=$_POST['day'];
    $year=$_POST['year'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass, phone, photo, sex-select, month,day,year)VALUES('".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$email."', '".$pass."', '".$phone."', '".$photo."', '".$sex_select."', '".$month."','".$day."','".$year."')") or die(mysql_error());
    header("location: index.php?remarks=success");
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: but there is no errors occurred, after entering input details, it show registered successfully.

Comment: have you used mysql_error? if yes and no error means your query is perfect but where is " registered successfully " msg you are printing. And I guess data is inserting into database.?