# Issue in inserting data into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created register form using php and jquery. I need to store input details to sql database.

I created config.php and included in index.php and submit.php file.

After entered input details, it shows "entered successfully,But still didn't store in database, may i know what is my mistake in config.php code, can anyone please help me?

This is my config.php:

```
    <?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "crop";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    ?>
```

and this is code_exec.php:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include('config.php');
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
    $month=$_POST['month'];
    $day=$_POST['day'];
    $year=$_POST['year'];

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass,`sex_select`, month,day,year)  
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass','$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
    ?>
```

Comment: i guess after validation in submit.php?

Comment: Try This Link May Help You... http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: from your question i have a feeling you did not write this code :D

Comment: Downvote this question to hell. He has been given a thorough overhall previously, didn't even bother to respond to the answer.

Comment: learning is good, but then start with basic login/form code,not the one where you call 10 php scripts. Before you learn when and how do you include different scripts.

Comment: beside title said registration using jQuery,there is not 1 line of jQuery/javascript that you posted.

Comment: have you try to include code_exec after validation in submit.php? after email check

Comment: as i said,after email check. before echo msg(1,"registered.html"); but you should change error message in code_exec to json format too because ajax expect json format. then you can check if error is there and print it. Or even better use same style as with other messages: `die(msg(0,"Wrong SQL query"));`

Comment: in code_exec change: `if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}` to `if (!$result) {
    die(msg(0,"Wrong SQL query"));
}` and also include code_exec after validation in submit. Have you done that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue in storing data into database in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228698/issue-in-storing-data-into-database-in-php)

Comment: This is a direct duplicate of your previous question. You need to be aware that if you ask a question twice, two sets of people will look at them, and if you get an answer twice, 50% of that effort will have gone to waste. Would it not be better, do you think, for you to ask a question once? Since you have duplicated questions before, I am downvoting. Please be more careful - if you do this too often, your account may be prevented from asking new questions.

Comment: btw you have syntax error in config.php (mysql_connect OR die, OR missing.

Comment: yes,as you need to put msg outside (like in functions.php). but other things should be changed too. Why not start fresh with some simple registration form that can be found on internet? basic form sumbit without ajax till you are better in this.

Comment: needs to be before that line

Comment: as i said you need to put msg function to functions.php and call that whenever you need it. I manage to get your code to work with some test db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this work at me.

code_exec:

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
include 'config.php';
session_start();
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$day=$_POST['day'];
$year=$_POST['year'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass,`sex_select`, month,day,year)  
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass','$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')");

if (!$result) {
 die(msg(0,"wrong query"));
}
?>
```

in submit.php add :

```
include 'code_exec.php';

// where member-area.php is the address on your site where registered users are
// redirected after registration.
echo msg(1,"registered.html");
```

in functions.php add msg:

```
function msg($status,$txt)
{
return '{"status":'.$status.',"txt":"'.$txt.'"}';
}
```

if this doesnt work check what error would script return, maybe you did not select right db or table name.

WARNING: this code should not be used in production, you should start using more secure mysqli or PDO functions, and you should use prepared statements, password hashing etc.

Comment: btw removed error_reporting(0), that was there by mistake.

Comment: in firefox you can use firebug, in chrome development tool, in IE also development tool.

Comment: i guess db is not selected, if your db is same as table name try changing query to `INSERT INTO crop.crop ` ...

Comment: first crop is database name, second crop is table name.

Comment: btw you ll get deprecated messages for mysql_functions. Start by learning [mysqli](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

Comment: still i didn't get solution. anyway thank you so much for your responses @Bojan Kovacevic

Comment: unpack and check this [zip](http://jqfiles.webege.com/crop.zip). Found it easier then posting all code here. You can check no error [here](http://jqfiles.webege.com/crop/)

Comment: I got it.....thanks a lot, in back-end why it shows month,year and date like 0000-00-00?

Comment: where? i doubt that as value in db is correctly entered.

Comment: this is the link i got it like, http://s11.postimg.org/xl1gd56n7/Untitled_1_copy.png

Comment: btw what is your table structure? Print `SHOW CREATE TABLE crop;` If you set `year`,`month` and `day` as `DATETIME` you would get error as in PHP script values in select boxes are integers (or strings which always work)

Comment: you cant put numbers 1-12 as `DATETIME` or `DATE`. Set day,month and year as integers or parse values together creating DATE object (YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: i said change them to `INT`, you cant use numbers 1-12, 1-31 or just year as `DATE` or `DATETIME`

Comment: after DB change check your script again (execute it) so that you have new values. If if doesnt work print result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE crop;` here

Comment: @ Bojan Kovacevic: may i know, how to retrieve that input details and display in front end.

Comment: what input details? list of registered users? If so, its basic `SELECT * FROM crop;` command and then print in form you want (for example table). Ofc you dont print passwords, but things like username, email ... This is really basic stuff. In pruduction your would need to hash password, use mysqli or PDO and prepared statements to prevent things like SQL injection etc but i guess you are far away from that part and are only learing basic stuff.

Comment: yes,  registered users..So that , can i display to generate encrypt of each password ?

Comment: cant help you with all different topic you need to learn, as it takes a lot of time. Google php hash password or something like that and learn what function to use. Even when you hash password (and later use hash comparation in login script) you dont show it in a listed registered user view. Password is private field used only to log, not as a information about some user.

Comment: Its ok @Bojan Kovacevic. Not an issue. Thank you so much for spent lot of time for my question.

Comment: np, good luck in learning new stuff. You ll need to learn a lot of different topics before using this as a real production site. wherever you handle personal informations like a passwords, you need to take care about security.

Comment: @bojan, I see you've mentioned SQL injection in the comments, but I am not sure it is a good idea to replicate the OP's security vulns in your answer. At the very least it is beneficial to add a warning that the code is not secure, in your answer itself.

Comment: @halfer good comment. I added warning. There are few things he should change so i didnt have time to made all changes in code so that it is secured.